# how to check if xml node is the root in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml

I made a algorithm that read from xml and this algorithm need to check if we are in the root node.

How can I check the node level in asp.net?

Thanks for any help

Baaroz

Comment: Can you provide more detail on your algorithm? Are you using a DOM or XMLReader or is it just a string?

Comment: Hi Simon,I am using dom (xmldocument)

Comment: If the current node is an XmlNode, check the ParentNode property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.parentnode(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code with System.Xml namespace :

```
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.Load(_url);

    XmlNode root = xDoc.FirstChild;
   if (root.Name.ToLower() == "rss")
   {
    //perform your logic
   }
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: @baaroz - here at Stack Overflow we don't thank people. We upvote their answers. +1 from me.